# Javascript: Check string to be the pattern of RegExp Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I need to find a solution for checking a string that can be the pattern of RegExp Object like this.
`str` => new RegExp(`str`) can run and return a regex to use with test(), match(), ...

How can I check `str` available to use like the above way?
(I am trying to create a component like the website regex101.com so I want to know how they can check and show errors in `regular expression` input)
Thank you a lot.

Comment: Maybe just do a `try catch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a try catch to test it:

```js
function isValidRegex(str) {
  try {
    new RegExp(str);
    return true;
  } catch(ex) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had an idea to use try-catch but I ignored it (lol). :)))))